# Git 'Everything up-to-date' push again

Tags: git

I know there are lots of questions that are asking the same but I haven't found the accurate answer for my specific issue.

I just set up a new remote git repo on my server and used:

```
git push --all origin
```

However, not everything was working on the remote server and I would like to push it again. No matter what I tried I always get the same message:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

**EDIT:**

I got this for `git status`: `HEAD detached at f6b6299 nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

As I mentioned above I messed something up on the remote (`hint: The 'hooks/post-receive' hook was ignored because it's not set as executable.`).

The first push was successful: `Enumerating objects: 121, done. Counting objects: 100% (121/121)...`

However, after I fixed the above error and I tried to push again I got the `Everything up-to-date` message. I want to push it again, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

What am I missing here and what to do to push it again to the remote?

Comment: The error message you're getting means that all *commits* are already sent. Remember that Git pushes commits, not files; if you have files you have never committed, those will never get sent.

Comment: @torek It seems like everything is committed. I get this message: `There are no changes to commit.`

Comment: What about the output from `git status`: are there untracked files that should be tracked and committed? Other than that, it looks like everything is OK. If it's not working, perhaps there's some sort of system difference, such that some program that works on your machine, just doesn't work on other machines.

Comment: Which changes do you expect to be sent to the server if there aren't any?

Comment: Which of the questions goes into detail on what they did, what happened and what they expected? General rules like creating a [mcve] or adhering to the good advise in [ask] are missing from your question as well.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt just updated the original question

Comment: @torek just updated the original question with the answers.

Comment: No you didn't, you still don't write how anyone here can reproduce the issue. Start with `git init`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes, I did update my original question you can check the history. This is not an issue that needs to be reproduced, it's just a question about how to re-push any commit anyone did anywhere previously. It's not specific to my use case.

Comment: Why did you detach the head? You can't push in that state. You can't do much of anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, this is quite significant:

> I got this for git status:
>
> ```
> HEAD detached at f6b6299
> nothing to commit, working tree clean.
> ```

The way `git push` works is pretty simple, but there are a lot of details to manage.  You most likely want to create a new branch name, or update some existing branch name, in your own repository to identify commit `f6b6299`.  It's hard to give a more specific answer without knowing much more about your particular situation.

> As I mentioned above I messed something up on the remote (`hint: The 'hooks/post-receive' hook was ignored because it's not set as executable.`)

This is a separate problem, that has to be addressed separately.  There's no way to fix this directly within Git itself.

## Long: What to know about `git push`

We start with the most basic thing to know about Git itself, which is: *Git is all about commits*.  Those new to Git often think it's about files.  It's not: it's about commits.  Commits *contain* files, which is where the files enter the picture, but the focus is on the commits.  Or, they might think that Git is about branches.  It's not: it's still about commits.  Branches allow us to *find* commits, and that's where branch names enter the picture.  Being able to find the commits is pretty important of course!  But it's still really all about the commits themselves.

#### What to know about commits

Every Git commit is numbered.  Each one gets a *unique* number, but the number isn't sequential.  We can't just count them: we can't list them as commit #1, commit #2, and so on.  Instead, we get these big ugly hash IDs.  They look random, but are in fact completely deterministic.  A string of digits and letters like `f6b6299` (but longer: this one has been abbreviated to a unique prefix of the full unique number) is actually a hexadecimal number, giving the raw number of this particular commit.

*This number is the same in every Git repository*, so I can tell if I have your commit by looking to see if I have a commit whose number starts with `f6b6299` (it has to exactly match the whole thing, so to be sure, I'd need the longer version).  Any Git repository can tell whether it has this commit or not by checking in its database.  The main database in a Git repository is full of stuff indexed by these numbers: that's how your Git stores your commits (and the supporting objects that go with them).

Every once in a while, you connect your Git to some other Git.  The two Gits have a sort of Git-sex where they exchange commits (unidirectionally though: one Git is the sender, the other is the receiver).  These are where `git push` and its opposite, `git fetch`, come in, but we'll get to those later.

Anyway, back to the commits: each one stores two things:

- A commit stores a full snapshot of every file that Git knew about at the time you, or whoever, made the commit.  These files are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  The de-duplication takes care of the objection that people have, that making a new commit when you've only *changed* one file out of thousands, would waste a ton of space.  It would, except that if there are 5000 files and you changed one, the new commit just *re-uses* 4999 files.

  This is completely safe because all files in a commit are forever read-only.  *No* part of *any* commit can ever be changed.  That's because the unique hash ID for a commit incorporates every single bit of the commit's data and metadata.  If you actually do extract a commit, modify something, and put it back, what you get is a new commit, with a new unique hash ID.  The existing commit remains unchanged.
- Meanwhile, each commit also stores some *metadata*, i.e., information about the commit itself.  The metadata include your name—or the name of whoever made the commit—and email address and some date-and-time-stamps and so on.  It includes the log message you see with `git log`, which is your chance to explain *why* you made the commit.

  Crucially for Git itself, though, Git adds something of its own to this metadata.  Each commit stores the raw hash ID of some set of *earlier* commits.  Most commits just store one hash ID, of their immediate parent.  (We won't cover the exceptions to this rule here.)

What this means for us here is simple enough: it means each commit, in effect, points *backwards* to the immediately-previous commit.  Let's draw this, using single uppercase letters to stand in for the actual, random-looking hash IDs:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, `H` is the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  It might be `f6b6299`, for instance.  Whatever it is, we could jot it down on paper, or on a whiteboard, or something, so that we know it.  Then we can type that big ugly hash ID in to various Git commands, such as `git log`.  Git will use that hash ID to look up, in its big database of "all Git objects including all commits", to see if it has that (and to check that it's a commit, too, as there are some other object types).

Of course, your Git repository really *does* have this commit, so Git finds it.  Git can therefore extract all the *files* that go with that commit: they're the data in the commit.  Meanwhile, Git can also extract all the metadata, so it can show that you made the commit, and when; and it can show your log message.  But most importantly for Git, it can find the *actual hash ID* of the commit that comes just *before* this commit, which we're calling `G`.

Using the hash ID of `G`, Git can extract commit `G`.  This gets it the full snapshot of all files—which Git can compare to the snapshot in `H`, for instance, to see what *changed*.  This also gets Git the metadata for `G` though, and that includes the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`.

Using the hash ID of `F`, Git can read that commit.  Git can keep doing this for *every commit in the chain*, working backwards from the latest, to the very beginning of history.  Each of these commits, as it traverses this backwards-looking chain, *is* the history, as stored in the Git repository.  And this all works by commit hash IDs: we just need to kick the whole thing off somehow by *saving* the *latest* hash ID somewhere.

#### Branch names

This is where branch names come in.  Given that we can find *every* commit if we write down the *last* one's hash ID, well, why don't we have the *computer* write it down?  Let's save the number—the hash ID—of the *last* commit in a file or something.  In fact, let's just make another little database, which holds names like `develop` and `feature/tall`.  In this database, let's have *Git* store the hash ID of the *last* commit in some chain.

We can draw that like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

That is, our names database, which holds things like branch names (but also tag names and other names), has in it the branch name `main`, which holds the hash ID of commit `H`.  By definition, that's the *last* commit on that branch.  It also holds the name `develop` which holds hash ID `J`, which by definition is the *last* commit on branch `develop`.

We say that the names *point to* the commits, and the commits *point to* their parents.  So `main` points to `H`, which points back to `G`, and so on.  Likewise, `develop` points to `J`, which points back to `I`, which points back to `G`.  Commits up through `G` are on *both* branches, while commit `H` is only on `main`.  If we want to emphasize this point, we can draw this same set of commits like this:

```
          H   <-- main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

This represents the *same Git repository*, with the same commits and names; we've just drawn it slightly differently, to make it clear where the branching branched off, and which commits are on both branches.

(Note how we're using the word *branch* rather loosely here.  See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

#### `HEAD`, or, how can we know which branch we're using?

Let's say we *do* have this:

```
          H   <-- main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

If we run `git checkout main` or `git switch main`, we'll be using the *name* `main`, and the *commit* whose hash ID is `H`.  If we run `git checkout develop` or `git switch develop`, we'll be using the *name* `develop`, and the *commit* whose hash ID is `J`.  We'd like a nice way to remember which name to use.  Let's do this:

```
          H   <-- main (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

Here, the special name `HEAD` tells us *which branch name we are using*.  We simply attach it to some branch name.  That's the name we're using!  If we have this setup, and make a *new* commit, Git will handle that process by writing out the new commit, giving it a new unique hash ID, and stuffing that hash ID into the *name* `main`.  The new commit will point back to commit `H`, because that's the commit we started with in order to *make* the new commit, and we will now have:

```
          H--K   <-- main (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

Here, `HEAD` is still attached to `main`, but now the *name* `main` means commit `K`.

The ideas to take away here are:

- branch names find commits;
- the special name `HEAD` finds a branch name; and
- as we add *new* commits, they point back to the commit we used to *make* the new commit, and Git writes the *new* commit's ID into the branch name.

This is what it means to be *on a branch:* that the special name `HEAD` is attached to that branch name.

#### Detached `HEAD`

What if, for whatever reason, we'd like to look at some *historic* commit?  Given:

```
          H--K   <-- main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

we might want to inspect commit `G`.  One way we could do that is to attach a new branch name *to* commit `G`:

```
          H--K   <-- main
         /
...--F--G   <-- inspect
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

and we could then `git checkout inspect` or `git switch inspect`, and we'd be on commit `G` and could look at it, and even make new commits:

```
          H--K   <-- main
         /
...--F--G   <-- inspect (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

Once we make a *new* commit, it gets a new hash ID:

```
          H--K   <-- main
         /
...--F--G--L   <-- inspect (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

with the branch growing in the usual way.

That's fine and is easy to do in Git, but Git doesn't *require* that we actually make this new name.  We can, instead, just make `HEAD` point *directly to some commit*.  That is, we can do this:

```
          H--K   <-- main
         /
...--F--G   <-- HEAD
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

If we do, and if we make a *new* commit now, we get this:

```
          H--K   <-- main
         /
...--F--G--L   <-- HEAD
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

This mode of operation, in Git, is called a *detached HEAD*.  You *can* work this way, but it gets annoying and painful, because *branch names* are where we normally store the last commit hash ID.

#### You don't normally want to work in detached HEAD mode

Suppose we've made commit `L` and *haven't* written down the hash ID on paper or whatever, and decide we want to look at `develop` and run `git checkout develop` or `git switch develop`.  We'll get this:

```
          H--K   <-- main
         /
...--F--G--L   ???
         \
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The special name `HEAD` no longer contains a raw hash ID.  It's not *detached* any more.  So ... how will we *find* commit `L`?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Without getting into a lot more "here's how you fix a mistake" parts, we just won't.  The commit will vanish from view and we will never see it again.  Eventually, Git will throw it away.  That's why we don't normally work in "detached HEAD" mode—except, that is, during an in-progress rebase.  But that's for other StackOverflow answers.

---

#### If you're in this mode and want to save a commit, give it a name

Let's say we *are* in this mode:

```
          H--K   <-- main
         /
...--F--G--L   <-- HEAD
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

and we'd like to have Git remember the hash ID of commit `L`.  The obvious thing to do is to make a *branch name* that points to commit `L`.  We can do that with any number of commands:

```
git branch save-me
```

or:

```
git checkout -b save-me
```

or:

```
git switch -c save-me
```

for instance.  All three create a new branch name, in this case `save-me`, that points to commit `L`.  The `git branch` command does that, but leaves `HEAD` detached:

```
          H--K   <-- main
         /
...--F--G--L   <-- HEAD, save-me
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

while the checkout and switch commands do that and then attach `HEAD` to that name:

```
          H--K   <-- main
         /
...--F--G--L   <-- save-me (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

So they're all more or less equally good, but if you'd like to be "on" your new branch, you can use the one that does that.

#### If there's already a branch name here, you can just use it

Suppose we are in *this* situation for some reason—we won't worry about why, just that we are:

```
          H   <-- main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop, HEAD
```

We can get back "on" branch `develop`, i.e., attach `HEAD` to it, without changing *commits*.  The name `develop` selects commit `J`; so does the name `HEAD`.  So:

```
git checkout develop         # or git switch develop
```

will give us:

```
          H   <-- main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Our `HEAD` is now attached again, and we're on branch `develop`, using commit `J`.  The only thing that changed is that we went from detached-HEAD mode to attached-HEAD mode, so that a new commit `K` will now extend the branch `develop`, by writing the new commit's hash ID into the branch name.

### We're finally ready to talk about `git push`

Now that you know how branch names work, we can look at what `git push` really does.  We have our Git call up some other Git, and the two Gits have that Git-sex I mentioned earlier.  Let's say that in *both* repositories, we both started out with the same set of commits, and some similar branch names.  *They* had:

```
          H   <-- main (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

When we ran `git clone` to copy this entire repository, we got all their commits and none of their branches:

```
          H   <-- origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

These funny `origin/*` names are *remote-tracking names* rather than *branch* names.  They let our Git find the commits, but they don't let us get "on" them.  If we try to use `git checkout` with these names:

```
git checkout origin/develop
```

Git will put us into "detached HEAD" mode.

Now, before `git clone` finishes, it goes on to make *one* branch name in our new repository.  The name it makes is the one we tell it to make with the `-b` option, when we use `git clone -b develop`:

```
          H   <-- origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

If we *don't* tell it something with `-b`, the one branch name our Git makes is based on whatever the other Git recommends.  Typically that's `master` (current Git and GitHub as of last year) or `main` (GitHub as of today, future Git perhaps as well), but if you're using GitHub, it's something you set using the web interface there.  So maybe we get:

```
          H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

We can now create our own branch names, such as `inspect` pointing to `G`, or whatever: our only constraints are that we have to pick some *existing* commit whenever we ask our Git to create a new branch name.<sup>2</sup>  We find those existing commits using branch names—which find *last* commits—or remote-tracking names like `origin/develop`, which were copied from that other Git's branch names; or we just run `git log` or `git log --all --decorate --graph --oneline` or whatever, and cut-and-paste raw commit hash IDs.  We create and destroy branch names as we like, with the one constraint: we have to pick some existing commit.

We can, of course, create *new* commits.  Once we create them, they exist in our Git repository.  We can now create new names that pick out these new commits.  We can do that by creating a new branch name pointing to some existing commit:

```
git checkout -b newbranch origin/develop

          H   <-- main, origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- newbranch (HEAD), origin/develop
```

and then make new commits:

```
          H   <-- main, origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
              \
               K--L   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

Note that there is no `origin/newbranch`, because their Git, over on GitHub or whatever, doesn't *have* a branch name `newbranch`.  They don't have commits `K-L` either.

So, now we run `git push origin newbranch`.  This directs our Git to call up their Git.  The short name `origin`, which Git calls a *remote*, stores the URL our Git uses to send messages to their Git, so as to make things happen with their repository.  Our Git calls up their Git; they look in their repository; we and they see that they *don't* have commits `K-L`; and we've told our Git to send these new commits, so our Git does just that.  Our Git packages up commits `K` and `L`, along with any files that we have that they don't.

Git figures all this out on its own, using the hash IDs.  Since hash IDs are universal across *all* Git repositories, and the fact that they *do* have commit `J` means that they have all the commits leading up to `J` too, they must have all the files that go with all those commits.  Our Git can send them something as small as possible to let them *build* commits `K` and `L` that store all the same files and metadata as our commits `K` and `L`, and will therefore have the same hash IDs.

Having sent over those commits, our Git then asks their Git to create or update their name `newbranch` so that it points to commit `L`.  Assuming they obey this request—our Git sends it as a polite request, not a forceful command, by default—they will now have:

```
          H   <-- main (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
              \
               K--L   <-- newbranch
```

in *their* repository.  They have our new commits *and* they have a name `newbranch`.  Our Git finishes up our `git push` action by seeing that they agreed to create `newbranch`, so our Git creates our own `origin/newbranch` to remember their `newbranch`, and now we have:

```
          H   <-- main, origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
              \
               K--L   <-- newbranch (HEAD), origin/newbranch
```

---

<sup>2</sup>There's a special mode with `git checkout --orphan` that we won't get into here, where we don't pick an existing commit.

---

#### `git push` with detached HEAD doesn't work very well

Suppose that, for whatever reason, we have a detached-HEAD situation like this:

```
            K--L   <-- HEAD
           /
          H   <-- main, origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

When we run `git push origin`, we'll ask *their* Git to take new commits and set branch names.  *But we don't have any branch name to identify commit `L`.*  So we won't even *send* them commits `K-L` unless we direct our `git push` specifically to do that.  Such a specification takes a form like this:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/newbranch    # don't do this
```

It's rarely a good idea to use this construction.  It *does work!*  It's just that this creates, in their Git repository, the new branch, but doesn't create any *branch* name in *our* repository.  It's a recipe for confusion, in other words.  We stay in our detached-HEAD mode and if we make more commits, they're not on any branch.

It's much more sensible, in this situation, to create a new branch name, or update some existing branch name.  For instance, we could just create the new name `newbranch` now and get on it:

```
            K--L   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
           /
          H   <-- main, origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

Now we can just `git push origin newbranch` as usual, and we and they will use the *same* branch name, `newbranch`, to identify commit `L`.  Ourselves from next year, or whoever else might work on/with these repositories, will be much happier with ourselves from today.

Note that if we want the other Git to *use* the new commits, we might need to put them on whatever branch name *they* will actually *use*.<sup>3</sup>  For instance, maybe we need to update their `main`.  If that's the case, we should probably first update *our* `main`:

```
git branch temp
```

will create a temporary name to hold commit `L`'s hash ID:

```
            K--L   <-- temp, HEAD
           /
          H   <-- main, origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

after which we can `git checkout main` and do a *fast-forward merge*<sup>4</sup> like this:

```
git switch main
git merge --ff-only temp
```

Since this all went well,<sup>5</sup> we can now delete the name `temp` entirely and draw this:

```
            K--L   <-- main (HEAD)
           /
          H   <-- origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

Now we can safely run `git push origin main`, to send commits `K-L` to them and ask them, politely, to update *their* branch name `main` to point to commit `L`.  If that all goes well, we have:

```
          H--K--L   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

and, because they're deploying the `main` branch—this assumes that's what they are deploying—they are now using the same commit, and hence the same files, as we were using.

---

<sup>3</sup>Ask yourself which branch name(s) they use, how, and why.  Each Git repository can use whatever names it likes, for whatever purposes; and different hosting systems, such as GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, and so on, provide different automated systems for using branches.  There are myriad possibilities.  Git provides tools and mechanisms, not pre-packaged solutions.

<sup>4</sup>A fast-forward merge is not a merge at all, but is often the right thing to do here.

<sup>5</sup>If it *didn't* go well, we're in good shape, because everything is saved permanently in commits, and we have names by which we can find all our commits.  Obviously we'll have to figure out what went wrong and fix *that*, but because commits are permanent—as long as we can find them anyway—and safe like this, we'll be able to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to delete specific branches on your remote and then push their local versions again.

Deleting a remote copy of the `<my-branch>` branch (this does not alter the local copy of `<my-branch>` in any way):

```
git push --delete origin <my-branch>
```

Then checkout `<my-branch>` and push it again:

```
git checkout <my-branch>
git push origin <my-branch>
```

For more information about deleting branches, have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/4744341).